# How to use page ID to custom URL for Wagtail

Tags: wagtail, custom-url

I don't like to use title in URL, this is not succinct. default:

```
http://example.com/work/[my-work]/
```

how to change  it to: `http://example.com/work/[page_id]/` like this:

```
http://example.com/work/18
```

Comment: You can change the slug of any wagtail page. When you are editing the page, click on "promote" and change the slug to anything you want, including the ID of the page (which you can find in the URL)

Comment: but this need manual for per change

Comment: Well yeah, we're working within an intelligent CMS. Having an ID in the URL isn't a very strong signifier for search engines to recognize what they're looking for, and an ID doesnt mean anything to the end user. So text-based slugs are preferred. 

You could also look into routable pages. https://learnwagtail.com/course/adding-routable-pages/ and https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/reference/contrib/routablepage.html. With a RoutablePage you can have both, and the ID can be completely automated. You'll need to customize the Page models' sitemap though.